# How to combine HLS streams one after another

Tags: python, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, rtsp, amazon-kinesis

I have an HLS stream that expires every 12 hours and a new link is generated. How can I create one static HLS stream?

One idea I've thought of is to keep refreshing the stream and forwarding it to one static URL? Is this possible and could anyone point me to resources on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is, you can make a static link like M3U8 file which will be containing the link of your HLS streaming service.

Thereafter, you can update your M3U8 file every 12 hours as HLS streaming link get updated.

Therefore, the M3U8 file will be a static link forever.

A brief introduction is given here about [M3U8 files](https://fileinfo.com/extension/m3u8).